# Soma de números em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu estou com dificuldade de fazer um exercício que pede o seguinte:

Usando JavaScript, solicite um número em uma caixa prompt, este número não pode ser maior que 50, caso o número seja maior, mostrar uma caixa de alerta para repetir o número.
Como resultado, mostrar todos os números pares de 0 até o número informado, o total de números pares e a soma destes números (todos os números digitados).

Estou no início de JavaScript, então não sei muita coisa ainda. Consegui fazer isso. E a soma não está dando certo, alguém pode me dar uma luz no restante?

```
document.write("EXERCÍCIO 13" + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
var num, par, contPar = 0, soma = 0;
num = prompt("Digite um número: ");
parseInt(num)
parseInt(soma)
soma = num
while (num != 0 || num > 50) {
    num = prompt("Digite um número abaixo de 50 ou 0 para finalizar:");
    soma = soma + num

if (num % 2 == 0)
    contPar = contPar + 1   
}
document.write("Quantidade de números Pares digitados: " + contPar + "<br/>" + "<br/>")
document.write("Soma dos números digitados: " + soma + "<br/>" + "<br/>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque

```
parseInt(num)
parseInt(soma)
soma = num
while (num != 0 || num > 50) {
    num = prompt("Digite um número abaixo de 50 ou 0 para finalizar:");
    soma = soma + num

if (num % 2 == 0)
    contPar = contPar + 1   
}
```

Por

```
soma = parseInt(num)
while (num != 0 || num > 50) {
    console.log(soma)
    num = prompt("Digite um número abaixo de 50 ou 0 para finalizar:");
    soma = soma + parseInt(num)

    if (num % 2 == 0)
        contPar = contPar + 1
}
```

Quando você faz

```
parseInt(num)
parseInt(soma)
```

Você está convertendo o valor da variável para inteiro e retornando, mas como você não salvou esse valor em uma variável essa conversão para inteiro se perdeu. O correto é você fazer isso e atribuir a uma variável, da seguinte forma:

```
soma = parseInt(num)
```

Assim a variável `soma` irá receber um número inteiro, vindo da conversão da variável `num`.

Mesmo que você tenha usado `parseInt` na variável `num`, quando ela receber um valor do `prompt` irá receber novamente um valor do tipo `string`

```
num = prompt("Digite um número abaixo de 50 ou 0 para finalizar:");
```

Então novamente ao somar terá que utilizar `parseInt` na variável ao somar

```
soma = soma + parseInt(num)
```

Comment: Agora ficou claro, muito obrigado!! E funcionou, valeu mesmo! :D